# How to initialize an object with private member from a text file in C++

Tags: c++

I am having trouble understanding how I can achieve this. I am trying to avoid setters and getters and public member.

I need to initialize objects from txt files.

I have created multiple classes.
In my main.cpp I create objects.
I then read from txt files and want to populate my objects.

```
class data{
private:
    int d;
    int p;
    vector<string> name;
public:
    ...constructor here...
    friend std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream&, std::ios&);
    ...destructor here...    

}
```

in main.cpp

```
data obj;
```

I am trying to initialize the object obj.

Comment: `std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream&, type&) { ... }`?

Comment: attributes are private, I cant write to them. I cant even select the attributes from the objects in main.cpp

Comment: Ok, then add `friend std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream&, type&);` in your class definition.

Comment: Not sure to understand, I have to add this to every class I have ?

Comment: You declare the overloaded `ifstream` `>>` operator as a `friend` to your class and you give it access to your class private data members allowing you to read directly from a file into your private class members.

Comment: @VHDLprog: "*I have to add this to every class I have ?*" That's what `friend`s are for.

Comment: If you don't like making `friend`s, make a public member function in your classes that the streaming operators can call. `std::ifstream& read(std::ifstream&);`. The formatted input operator could then look like: `std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream& ifs, type& t) { return t.read(ifs); }`

Comment: I am confused about this function. What does it do? It allows me to read the data? and If I want to write to the members I use ofstream&?.

I still have to make a function in main to open up the file and do my stuff there right ?

Comment: Is there any example on how to use 
***friend std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream&, type&); ***
I cant make it work

Comment: "_What does it do?_" - whatever you make it to do - The `friend` part in the class definition lets the free function have access to class member variables. If you go the other way, not making the streaming operator a friend, it's clearer. It'll just call a member function (and they have access to the member variables). There are plenty of examples where at SO. If I stumble across one that fits, I'll post it here, but you'll probably find one faster when actively searching.

Comment: I understand the friend part, I don't understand how I can use that function to read from a file.

Comment: @VHDLprog: Question: Why did you choose to go with `operator>>`? I believe there would be only one file for each type of object, right? If so, wouldn't it be more readable and contained like `data obj; obj.load( "filename" );`? Just curious. If there are multiple such files, is there a possibility that those can be read using some `Config` type and then be used from there? Also, it'd be helpful if you added a few sample lines of your data file with your question.

Comment: I did not specifically choose that. People here been recommending it. I am confused and don't understand. I want to read data from a file and fill up my object, my members are private.

Comment: @VHDLprog: Can you write a member function `load()` and do your loading-from-file stuff in there? Just open the file, read the data, extract the values that you need, load up your data member and go on with your processing. If you can do that, it should not be difficult to extract/refactor that functionality later.

Comment: @VHDLprog Re: _"I am confused and don't understand."_ You are not the only one feeling that way around here.

Comment: @Azeem How ? I can't access my members since they are private.

Comment: @VHDLprog: Here's an example: https://godbolt.org/z/e9Dyo9.